# file handling in vapor

Tags: php, swift, vapor

I am wondering if there is a possibility to create file-handling code in Vapor ? (Swift)

For example, I want to create a folder on the server, then copy an existing file from one location on the server to this folder.

Is this possible in Vapor ?

I did the file-copying in `php` as can be seen in the below function that actually copies a file from source to destination :

```
<?php
function copyr($source, $dest, $permissions = 0701)
{
    // Check for symlinks
    if (is_link($source)) {
        return symlink(readlink($source), $dest);
    }

    // Simple copy for a file
    if (is_file($source)) {
        copy($source, $dest);
        return chmod($dest, 0204);
    }

    // Make destination directory
    if (!is_dir($dest)) {
        mkdir($dest, $permissions);
    }

    // Loop through the folder
    $dir = dir($source);
    while (false !== $entry = $dir->read()) {
        // Skip pointers
        if ($entry == '.' || $entry == '..') {
            continue;
        }

        // Deep copy directories
        copyr("$source/$entry", "$dest/$entry", $permissions);
    }

    // Clean up
    $dir->close();
    return true;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code, it may work in your case.

Suppose I like to copy one file from my project to a new folder outside my project folder.

```
// Get the project directory
let directory = DirectoryConfig.detect()
let filePath = directory.workDir + "../mydoc"
```

Now create the directory using **FileManager**. It will create a folder outside your project folder.

```
do {
   try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: filePath, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil)
   } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription);
   }
```

Now, get your absolute file path with extension that needs to be copied.

```
 let myfile = directory.workDir + "README.md"
 let destPath = directory.workDir + "../mydoc/README.md"

    do {
        try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: URL(fileURLWithPath: myfile), to: URL(fileURLWithPath: destPath))
        print("Copy success")
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription);
    }
```

You will see the file is copied. This is working in my local PC. I can't grantee for the server due to the server security.